# Can we avoid the search stemming "chromes"?

Tags: feature-request, search

Lately a few people have asked about a particular malware app. It's named "Chromes" to disguise it as a genuine app, "Chrome". The problem is, when you search for "Chromes" on the site, the search engine returns a lot of results about "Chrome": it's applying stemming to the name.

As a result, we get lots of duplicate questions about the same malware, and it's hard for reviewers to find the original question to mark as duplicate. It also means the "Related questions" aren't relevant at all.

Is there a way we can avoid stemming for this particular word, so that when people are searching for "Chromes" malware, they get relevant results? Or is there some other workaround to help people find relevant questions and avoid posting duplicates?

Comment: Work-around: [put the term in "double quotes"](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22chromes%22) when searching. Got me 5 hits, only two of them were "wrong" because the writers forgot the apostrophe ("Navigate to chromes profile directory …", "I cleared chromes data…"). Afraid not much that *we* can do about the "related questions".

Comment: @Izzy Hmm, I could have sworn I tried that already and it didn't work, but I tried it just now and it was fine. I guess you could post that as an answer...

Comment: Happens, and no need for embarrassment. Had a similar thing in a different context not that long ago :) // Answer posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a full solution, but at least a work-around: [put the term in "double quotes"](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22chromes%22) when searching. Got me 5 hits, only two of them were "wrong" because the writers forgot the apostrophe ("Navigate to chromes profile directory …", "I cleared chromes data…") – which is correct as per the search terms.

Afraid not much that *we* can do about the "related questions" – nor for new users even if they use the search.